# Technical requirements for Flash AS3 image manipulation and saving application

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3

I am building a Flash AS3 application that allows users to modify images, and then submit-save them to a server.
The user will then have the ability to log in and access these saved images in a thumbnail gallery. They can either delete an image or click a thumbnail to view it at original size.

I am comfortable with the front end having built something similar in AS2 and Flash 8 a few years back.
What will be required for the backend?
I assume some type of PHP-MySQL database is needed. Not sure about hosting issues requirements as the AS2 application I built never sent any actual binary data, but rather data describing the image transformations. I assume I will need to make use of byteArray?

Is there an existing tutorial or code sample that does something similar available for viewing-download?

Are there any security restriction 'gotchas' associated with FP9 -10 I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

the most simple way is to create the image in the client ... get a `BitmapData` snapshot of the image using `BitmapData::draw` ... convert this to `JPEG` or `PNG` using the [as3corelib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/), that offers encoders for both formats ... and then just send the raw binary data to the server (store it into the `data` property of your `URLRequest`) and there, store it to the file system (retrieve it in [`$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php)) ... so the whole storage process is just a couple of lines ...

you will need a database of course, for session management (you could rely on PHPSESSION only, but personally i don't trust it), login, registration and to store which image belongs to which user ...

so yeah, the whole netcode/backend/storage thing etc. will be quite a piece of cake (btw. you might wanna look into [amfphp](http://www.amfphp.org/)) ... designing a good interface and implementing the galery view etc. will be the biggest chunk i guess ...

there are no real security gotchas, as long as your SWF comes from the same server, that it communicates to ...

so good luck then ... ;)

greetz

back2dos

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared host, php and mysql are probably already available to you, that is a good way to get started.

In terms of flash communicating with the server, you will have to find a way to turn your pictures into a stream of bytes (byteArray sure), and then use flash's send() to post them to the server. [Sending XML Out From Flash](http://www.kirupa.com/web/xml/XMLsending1.htm)

Using php you can receive the images and save them to the db, and show them (turn the stream of bytes back into an image with gd -- [gd docs](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php/))

Also: you may not ever have to send a stream of bytes if you can find a way to have flash describe the transformations, and have gd repeat them, just a thought.

> Are there any security restriction 'gotchas' associated with FP9 -10 I need to be aware of?

Maybe, if you are posting data to a different server, you have to enable it with some xml [Send data from Flash to PHP on a different server](http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=242208)